# Angularjs doesnot print from function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="canerApp" ng-controller="canerCtrl">
        <br> {{text}}f
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('canerApp', []);
app.controller('canerCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.text ="ff";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this works and prints

```
fff
```

as you can see here

http://plnkr.co/edit/gP2NcC38JPsabQFacGkb?p=preview

but this doesnot work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
        <br> {{text}}f
        <br> {{text}}fh
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app=  angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.text="afasfa";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

can be seen here
https://plnkr.co/edit/1I90i5ANdrA6OUmZry65?p=preview

they totally same except controller and app nmes.

i spent one hour but couldnot figure out. ANd also couldnot find online error finders to validate if everything is true.

Comment: add `https` in your second code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Above suggestion can be seen [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ivUsQBpop2864XP9s81s?p=preview)
Working fine now.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/8UtFzxuoo50bIVNrNbNV?p=preview but why does ths work wthout https

Comment: srry this http://plnkr.co/edit/jliZDa?p=preview

Comment: again same issue, please check your link before pasting,
check your url if it have `https` in it, if it have `https` then you have to use all the cdn using `https` protocol

Comment: if it has solve your problem can you please accept my answer as resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Actually the difference is that in your first code you are using `http` protocol plnkr and in your second code you are using `https` plnkr and using `http` protocol for angular library.

So just change protocol to `https` in script tag.

Thanks to @Ashu Jha for plnk https://plnkr.co/edit/ivUsQBpop2864XP9s81s?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I usually use code.angular.org for my angular cdn site.
And In case of yours http to https was the error.
you can find these kind of bugs directly using console tab of the browser
In your case error is

```
"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/1I90i5ANdrA6OUmZry65?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."
```

Try This along with https.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
         <br> {{text}}f
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app=  angular.module('myApp',[]);
        app.
        controller('myController', function($scope){
            $scope.text="afasfa";
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```